# Decodificador y Display de 7 segmentos- Tinkercad

Tags: arduino, tinker

Hace mucho tiempo no escribia, como estan? No se en este espacio deba hacer esta consulta, pero por las dudas lo voy a intentar. Tengo que hacer funcionar sencillamente este display de 7 segmentos en conjunto de mi decodificador. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ven, en la imagen se ve mi conexion y segun yo parece estar bien. No le veo ningun tipo de error, pero sin embargo no funciona como deberia. Ya me paso anteriormente con otro intento que estaba bien armado pero tampoco funcionaba como deberia. Que es lo que he hecho mal? Si es que alguien me puede ayudar con esto, lo agradeceria. Desde ya, muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Este es un sitio de programación así que tu pregunta está fuera de lugar. Pero te voy a dar unos tips: Tu fuente es muy pequeña, seguramente ese chip anda a mínimo 3V y tu tienes 2 de 1.5v pero separadas, luego necesitas unas resistencias en cada pin de la pantalla para que no se queme

Comment: Pense que se podia postear, pero gracias por el consejo, lo voy a intentar!